# Batch PATH with Quotes

Tags: batch-file

How can check if path has quotes or not, and add it if not have? I know i can make something like:

```
set /p path="My path "
"%path%"
```

But i have problems with quotes

```
C:\My folder --> "%path%" --> "C:\My folder" --> Good
```

If the user put a path with quotes

```
"C:\My folder" --> "%path%" --> ""C:\My folder"" --> Wrong
```

I can't use double quotes because the external command line i call not work and give me error. So how i can add "" only if not found in path? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove quote before using it, try:

```
set path=%path:"=%
```

`path` has not quote any more.

Example:

```
@echo off

set path="a b c"

set path=%path:"=%

echo %path%
```

Output

```
a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't test this as I'm writing from my phone, but can't you just assume there are double quotes and do a find & replace:

```
set path=%path:""="%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%var%") do set "var=%%~i"
  echo %var%
```

%var% has no double quotes around after the for loop.

Btw: you should not use cmd commands as batch variables (PATH).

Answer (score 1):

Remove all quotes, and then add quotes around it:

```
set path=^"%path:"=%^"
```

Carets (`^`) are used to escape the quotes' special meaning so `set` will include them in the variable.